# Unresolved dependencies

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

I am trying to install

`apt-get -f install ntp git build-essential libssl-dev libdb-dev libdb++-dev libboost-all-dev libqrencode-dev`

on Ubuntu and get dependency errors, when I try to install with all dependencies like

`sudo apt-get -f install g++ g++-4.8 libstdc++-4.8-dev libc6-dev libc6 libdb-dev libdb++-dev libboost-all-dev libqrencode-dev g++ libc-dev libc6-dev libboost-dev libboost-*-dev libboost-iostreams-dev libboost-mpi-dev libboost-mpi-python-dev libc6 libssl1.0.0`

I get a second error
`libboost-iostreams1.54-dev : Depends: libboost-iostreams1.54.0 (= 1.54.0-4ubuntu3) but 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.3 is to be installed
libssl-dev : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (= 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2) but 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.5 is to be installed
libxml2-dev : Depends: libxml2 (= 2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4) but 2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4.3 is to be installed`

I cannot seem to be able to get past that error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is trying to install a different version of the dependency.

try

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libboost-iostreams1.54.0 libc6 libssl1.0.0 libxml2
```

then try to install again

Comment: I get `libxml2 is already the newest version.
libssl1.0.0 is already the newest version.
libboost-iostreams1.54.0 is already the newest version.
libc6 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.` I have already tried to remove all the packages and reinstall but it gives a `After this operation, 656 MB disk space will be freed.
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'` warnings, I am not sure if I should proceed